# Power Query - Date1=Date2 +/- 3 days

Tags: date, powerquery

I need to introduce a tolerance of +/- 3 days to an existing Custom Column query. How can I do this?

I have an existing custom column that has an "if Date1=Date2 then xxxx" query, which works fine but want to add a tolerance.

Comment: Did this answer work for you?

Answer (score 0):

Test if dates in column AAA are 3 days away from TargetDate

= if Number.Abs(Number.From([AAA])-Number.From(TargetDate)) = 3 then  ...

Comment: For within tolerance +/-3 days: ` <= 3 `